# Infinite recursion in function

Tags: c++

In such a snippet:

```
struct A;
struct B {
    B(int k): k_(k) { }
    int k_; 
    operator A() const;
 };

 struct A {
     B k_;
 };

 B::operator A() const
 {
    return A(B(this->k_));   
 }
```

clang produces a warning (in the conversion operator):

```
 warning: all paths through this function will call itself [-Winfinite-recursion]
```

And  consequently when I do:

```
int main()
{
     A a = B(1);
}
```

the program fails with segmentation fault.

Can anybody, please, explain why there is infinite recurcsion.

Answer (score 7):

```
A a = B(1);
```

Lets first construct a `B` object with `B(1)` through the constructor that takes `int k`.

Now, let's use the user-defined conversion operator to cast this `B` into an `A` to make it fit `a`. This returns `A(B(this->k_));`.

Let's construct an `A` object using a newly-constructed `B` object that uses the same `k_`. The only fitting constructor is the copy constructor/move constructor that wants a `const A&`/`A&&`. We can use the user-defined conversion operator to cast the newly-constructed `B` object to an `A`, let's do that.

This will construct `A(B(this->k_));` *again*.

There's your infinite recursion.